# How can I generate a UPC barcode with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, barcode, prawn

I've been exploring this with Barby, which appears to be a very nice gem, but it doesn't seem to support UPC codes (which seems odd to me).

Is there some other (good, clean) way to do this in Ruby?  Or some way that I'm overlooking to generate UPCs with Barby?

Answer (score 0):

I *just* figured the answer out after composing the question.  UPCs are also known by the (much less friendly) name "EAN-13".  So you just use the EAN13 barcode class and you're good to go... I'll post code later if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

EAN-13 is a superset of UPC-A, and is the main class in barby. You have to use the following construct:

```
require 'barby/barcode/ean_13'

barcode = Barby::UPCA.new(data)
```

Note that you need to remove the checksum digit of your value before passing it to Barby, or else the barcode will be wrong.